# API thru Heroku custom domain, hostname not in DNS cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, heroku, dns

I am attempting to connect my website, which is on Heroku, to an API that retrieves a user's shopping data from another a separate website.

I can successfully connect to the API using the command line and my browser; but I cannot do the same in production. When I try to do that, I receive the error in the logs `Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache`.

I suspect this is because my *custom* domain has been registered for Oauth redirect, but not my *Heroku* domain.

I am allowed to set up additional domains for Oauth redirect. Before making this request to the API admins to set up an addt'l domain, I would appreciate if anyone could confirm or deny that this is the cause of my problem, and if setting up my Heroku domain would resolve it; or if there is a way I can use my custom domain exclusively, which seems more straightforward.

Thank you! I have provided some details below.

**Successful API call via command line and browser**

*Direct user to OAuth2 login (I do this part in a web browser):*
`https://www.example.com/shop/oauth2/?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&state={some_unique_state}&redirect_uri={your_site_url}`

*Successful user login, browser redirected to:*
`{your_site_url}?code={auth code}&state={some_unique_state echoed back}`

I then use the code provided in the redirect url in the following curl command.

*Get token and jsessionid:*
`curl -v -X POST -u {client_id}:{client_secret} -H "Content-Length: 0" "https://www.example.com/api/v2.0/token?code={code}"`

jsessionid and token are used in the following curl command.

*Retrieve data:*
`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" "https://www.example.com/api/v2.0/user/cart;jsessionid={jsessionid}?flags=true"`

**Unsuccessful attempt to do the same in production (Heroku, rails)**

In production, I can successfully get the user through the Oauth2 login and generate the auth code. I receive the DNS error message after I try to get the token and the jsessionid via a curl command in a controller method. I have confirmed that curl works for a simple task (rendering http://www.google.com) in that controller method; and I have also confirmed that I am successfully assembling all the needed variables in that method. The exact same curl command fails when executed via the controller method in production as compared to via the command line on my local machine.

Thank you for any clues you may provide; I am relatively new to API integration, so I definitely could be missing something basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the API team blocked my IP address because it was coming from Heroku. This company blocks IP addresses from cloud providers for security reasons. So I had to get a static API and then ask the team to whitelist it.

I got the static IP through Heroku's [Proximo](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo). I then had to use RestClient to invoke the static IP when making a request to the API.

In my controller method:

```
RestClient.proxy = ENV["PROXIMO_URL"] if ENV["PROXIMO_URL"]
retrieve_rest = RestClient::Request.execute(
  method: :get,
  :url => the_url,
  :headers => {"Authorization": "Bearer #{token}"})
    {|response, request, result| response }
result = JSON.parse(retrieve_rest)
```